# Bandwidth utilization is more than max speed

Tags: centos, bandwidth

Ethtool shows max speed is 1Gb/s. But in glances/SAR results in more than 1.7Gb/s.
Can somebody clarify this...

```
# ethtool ethX | grep -i speed
    Speed : 1000Mb/s
```

there is no dropped packets till now:

```
# cat /sys/class/net/ethX/statistics/tx_dropped
0

RX packets:159025710994 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:36682 frame:0
TX packets:121415304749 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
```

[image]

Note: Bonding is not configured

Comment: Is the UDP traffic you are feeding meaningful or just trying to overload it?

Comment: can you show `txdrops/s`?

Comment: can we see tx_dropped *while* Tx/s is showing 1.7Gbps?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro plz check my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simply having a larger value than the capacity of an interface on the output side, does not mean the interface is sending all that traffic; it means however you are trying to send all that traffic and overloading at least the interface.

Most of the extra traffic will be dropped. Have a look at the overrun value.

> If the capacity of the interface is exceeded, the frame that is
>   currently being  received is dropped and the overrun counter is
>   incremented.

PS Having a SCP doing this does not match much the behaviour of a TCP based application, and much less SCP, which is known for being slow. It seems much more typical of a UDP based/multicasting/torrent based application. I strongly suspect something is being overlooked.

Comment: Has the destination a 10Gbps interface or is a jumbo-enabled interface/network?